# Is it possible to implement MS SSO without client secret in Web App?

Tags: authentication, oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, single-sign-on

I have a Web app which MS SSO is implemented.
I have implemented SSO using client ID, Client Secret Id, Callback Url's and Scopes. But one of my client is not willing to share the client secret ID, they're saying it's possible to implement MS SSO without client secret. The only scope I'm using is *user.read* which allow them to login into the portal.

I went through a quite a few MS docs and I couldn't find any leads.
Is it really possible to implement this without Client secret

Since I'm not able to see a solution without client secret, I haven't tried anything.

Answer (score 0):

The client secret ID, sometimes called an application password, is a string value your app can use in place of a certificate to identity itself. It enables confidential applications to identify themselves to the authentication service when receiving tokens at a web application location. You may consider using a certificate as a credential instead of using a client secret string.

For example, you may find the following description in Azure when registering an app for SSO:

[image: Certificates & secrets page in Azure]

Comment: The client secret ID is only specific to that application not the whole AD, right? My client is concered about I'll be able to fetch whole AD data using this secret ID.

Comment: There are permissions which we can enable like user.read which help me with sign in the user and get basic profile details.

Comment: The client secret will only grant access to the specific application in question. This may or may not be an issue depending on what API permissions have been granted to the application, but in your scenario with only user.read granted I would not be concerned.